# Adding a percentage to every cell in a column in LibreOffice calc

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet with about seventeen hundred rows and I need to add 3% every cell in a column.

Example:

```
Column
------
1800
1500
5435
3583
3544
etc
```

I need to figure out what 3% of 1800 is then add it to that number. Then do that for every row.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ to the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"!

Comment: Sorry for the time it took to actually get around to doing this. I was away from work for a few weeks. Thanks for the answer, it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that update is to be static, as in "just change the numbers in the first column";

1. Type 1.03 in any cell
2. Select the cell with 1.03 in it, hold CTRL and hit C
3. Select the cells with numbers in the column you wish to update
4. Select "Paste special" in the menus or Ribbon (depending on Excel or Calc version)
5. Select "(*) Multiply" in the paste special dialog.
6. Click "OK"

*I might have missed something here as I type this from memory*

Comment: Good answer; I like it better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

To add 3%, multiply by 1.03 (or 1,03 for some locales).  Enter this formula in cell B1 and [fill down](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Fill#Down).

```
=A1*1.03
```

The result:

```
A       B       Formula for B
~~~~    ~~~~    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1800    1854    =A1*1.03
1500    1545    =A2*1.03
5435    5598    =A3*1.03
3583    3690    =A4*1.03
3544    3650    =A5*1.03
```

To quickly select a range, enter `B1:B1700` in the [Name Box](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Formula_Bar#Name_Box).